# json rpc hex string weird padding/encoding

Tags: json-rpc, encoding, hex

When sending eth_call to get erc20 token WETH name and symbol I get hex response padded with bunch of zeros and a mysterious digit '2'.

for symbol I get response:

"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045745544800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

for name I get response:

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d5772617070656420457468657200000000000000000000000000000000000000"

When I convert responses to utf8 string I get:

```
��������������������������������WETH 
�������������������������������Wrapped Ether
```

The routine to decode hex strings from ethereum.js unpads only up to first '2' that it finds. Although padding with zeros continues until actual chars begin.

Why such a 'weird' encoding of response and how to properly decode it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are encoded using [solidity abi](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/abi-spec.html)

- The first 32 bytes is the offset where string is present within the response: `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020`. So the string starts at position 20h = 32.
- At specified offset the first 32 bytes indicates the length of the string: `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004`. So string has length 4h = 4.
- Following the length the next 4 bytes are the string itself: `57455448`. From a utf-8 you have "WETH".

Comment: Thanks @Ismael. ethereum rpc spec on encoding is very loose: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#hex-value-encoding
only two options: quantities and unformatted data.
How do I know what encoding was used for data? I know that response is supposed to be string from method ABI definition. But how am I supposed to figure out what encoding was used for that string?

Comment: @Sharas The exceptions to that rule are when you interact with a contract, for example data field in eth_sendTransaction, eth_call; the returned data from eth_call; etc.